# Save preferences and use them in other platform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to ask if it's possible to save preferences in unity editor and use them when project is built and access them from other platform.

For example, I have set n=5 then saved it using playerprefs in unity editor and then I want to get the same integer on other platform when the project is build.

Is there any possible way to achieve this type of problem?

Comment: thats what defaults are for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like what you want is turning your data (the value of `n` in your example) into assets in your builds.
`PlayerPrefs` does not fit your need because it does not create assets at the build time that could be loaded back during run time. Instead, it is used to serialize data generated during run time to users' devices and use across application sessions (by session I mean the time from launch to quit an application).

My suggestions would be finding someway to serialize your data into assets that Unity can read. There are at least two ways of doing such thing:

1. Using [`ScriptableObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ScriptableObject.html). `ScriptableObject` is a class that inherits from `UnityEngine.Object` that is designed for serializing data as assets. Here is a simple example:

   ```
   [CreateAssetMenu("my_data.asset", "My Data")]
   public class Data : ScriptableObject
   {
       [SerializeField]
       private int _n;

       [SerializeField]
       private string _someString;

       public int N { get { return _n; }}
       public string SomeString { get { return _someString; }}
   }
   ```

   The normal usage would be defining your data class , say `Data`, that inherits from `ScriptableObject`. Then, you put desired data into it as serialized fields (`_n` and `_someString` here). The attribute [`CreateAssetMenu`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CreateAssetMenuAttribute.html) is used to create a menu item in the Unity editor for you to create the asset.
   After doing this, you can use the data in your `MonoBehaviour` by referencing it through a field marked with `[SerializeField]` just like any other Unity assets (like materials or sprites):

   ```
   public class SomeMono : MonoBehaviour
   {
       [SerializeField]
       private Data _data;

       void Awake()
       {
           Debug.Log("Data.SomeString is " + _data.SomeString);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Serialize the data into your own format (JSON, BSON, XML, whatever you like) and save them and read back as [`TextAsset`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAsset.html). Here is an example:

   ```
   public class SomeMono2 : MonoBehaviour
   {
       [SerializeField]
       private TextAsset _text;

       void Awake()
       {
           // Assumes that the data is just a plain string sequence.
           // However, it could be any text data you like.
           Debug.Log(_text.text);
           // Or you can serialize your data as bytes
           // byte[] byteData = _text.bytes
       }
   }
   ```

   Please note that Unity only automatically identifies files with extension `txt` (and maybe `json`? not quite sure about this one) as text assets.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you'd be better off using JSON and serializing your data. In the desktop, Unity saves PlayerPrefs to the registry. In Android, it is saved to a manifest file. So, in other words.. No, PlayerPrefs is not a cross-platform kinda thing. Furthermore, if this is "save-game" data, you should know that PlayerPrefs is used to store simple data like an Options menu. For saving an entire save game file you are going to want to use something a little more robust.